# Why does my homepage look like this?

Tags: magento2

My homepage isn't showing up correctly. How do I fix this?

[image: Homepage]

EDIT 1:
I noticed that the page source tries to load this stylesheet, which doesn't exist:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://www.example.com/pub/media/styles.css" />
```

EDIT 2:

I have already tried clearing the cache and doing the static contect deploy.

EDIT 3:

I did not modify less files.

Comment: have u done the the static content deploy

Comment: have you changed anything in `less` files?  have you tried `php bin/magento cache:flush` and then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`?

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered similar issues when i started working on for the first time. I had used to clean the cache, Static contents etc, but was not able to get desired result.

the Only key is in using the CLI commands in proper order.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

I hope that u did not do any changes in code & installed the magento store for and found these issues. if this is the case this might work for you. Happy coding.